# Advantages of ASP.NET login controls

Tags: asp.net

I want to know how is asp.net login controls better than classic login form.
By classic, I mean having a form with a user id text box and password textbox, a submit button that validates the id&password.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx

Is there more security with ASP.NET login controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Login control

1 You can interact  with security architecture generated by `Aspnet_regsql.exe tool security`.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

2 You avoid develop the form => reduce developement time.

3 You use  all functions validation added to login control.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login_methods(v=vs.80).aspx

Aspnet_regsql Reference :

Link `Aspnet_regsql` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

Others links about subject :

Link RoleManager : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb(v=vs.100).aspx

Link MemberShipUser: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.membershipuser(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit is it's built for you and you can 'Drop it in'

It ***can*** be more secure if you wrote an insecure 'Classic' login form

Comment: can u elaborate insecure 'classic' login form. Having a form with id and passwd textboxes and a submit button that validates the login considered insecure? If yes, could you provide some references where I can read about implementing a more secure login.

Comment: @crazyTechie I cant elaborate any more without seeing the code. Think SQL injection, XSS - The .Net controls abstract most of that away for you. Your 'Classic form' might be perfectly secure.

Comment: My code doesn't have much logic. Code under submit_click function calls a webservice that takes id and password as parameters and returns true/false

Answer (score 0):

Easy: You don't have to re-invent the wheel. You get a well designed and tested code, instead of writing your own and introduce bugs.
They are also very easy to use, and integrates well with the rest of the platform using providers.